# Delete duplicates MS-SQL with minimum date and multiple keys

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a big table that has duplicates as such:

- `number` (primary key),
- `group` (primary key),
- `Division` (primary key),
- `dateChange`.

Example:

```
1,2,3,20121015

1,2,3,20120101

1,2,3,20110101

2,2,2,20121010

2,2,2,20120101
```

result should be:

```
1,2,3,20121015

2,2,2,20121010
```

I have tried many combinations including group by the primary key with minimum "changeDate"
but nothing seems to work perfectly.

I want to have something like this:

```
delete from table where (number,group.devision,changeDate) not in 
(select from table(number,group,devision,Max(changeDate)) 
group by (number,group.devision)
```

But I dont think it is a valid MS-SQL syntax.

Your help will be very appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete all rows except for the latest for a `number, group, Division` combination.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number, group, Division 
                                       ORDER BY dateChange DESC) RN
         FROM   YourTable)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
delete table from
table inner join (select 
number, group, division, changeDate, row_number() over 
(partition by number, group, division order by changeDate desc) as ranker
from table) Z
on table.number  = Z.number and table.group = Z.group and 
table.changeDate = Z.changeDate and Z.ranker != 1
```